# Does Richfaces 3.3.3 ship with jQuery-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jquery working in my Richfaces 3.3.3 application. 
I added the following to include it from Richfaces:

```
<a4j:loadScript
    src="resource:///org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js" />
```

I'm now trying to use the jquery-ui datePicker component but am getting the following error:

```
jQuery("#startDate").datePicker is not a function
```

Here is my code that is causing it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Call constructor
    var calendar = new App.Calendar();

});


// Constructor
App.Calendar = function() {

    jQuery('#startDate').datePicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

};
```

Is there another script I need to include from Richfaces?
Or even download and include the jquery-ui file manually?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to look into http://primefaces.org - You can use primefaces together with your existing richfaces application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richfaces 3.3.3 doesn't include jquery-ui.

You should be able to download and include the jquery-ui on your pages, but why do you need it, richfaces has by itself a lot of UI components, including a datepicker like component.

See: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf

Comment: Yes I downloaded the jquery-ui plugin and have it working with my application. The main reason for wanting to use the jquery datepicker over Richfaces one is it's ability to have separate drop down months and years. Our current calendar has this look and customers would kick up a fuss if I introduced the way the months/years are displayed in richfaces datepicker.